# How to pass data from server side node (express) to client side script

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js

Very new to node so please excuse the basic question. I've looked through previous questions but I'm still unsure of how to work this out myself.

I have a node application running that does a bunch of data retrieval calling an external REST api. I'd like to be able to use this data and do stuff with it on the client side with d3, etc.

My express app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var stylus = require('stylus');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
// bunch of external api stuff
.
.
.
```

Then I have app.js in express/public/javascripts

```
window.app = {}
// d3 stuff - id like to get some server side data in here
indow.app.RenderGraph = function (node, width, height) {

    var   nodes
        , links
        , canvas
        , canvasBorder
        , force
        , charge = -500
        , gravity = 0.17
        , linkDist = 70
        , nodeRadius = 30
          // The function used to build the color
              // scale used to paint the nodes.
            , fill = d3.scale.category20(); 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var node = $("#canvas").get(0);
    window.app.RenderGraph(node, 400, 400);
});
```

Comment: You can add some app route with receiver of external data. Client side can use `ajax` by this route. What's problem?

Comment: @AikonMogwai thanks for the comment. I've got an app route now and am able to pass the data to the client side.  so cool!